# Ramifications of uninstalling GCC 4.7 in leu of GCC 4.6 in Quantal?

Tags: nvidia, apt, gcc

I currently have both the [gcc-4.6 [image: Install gcc-4.6]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gcc-4.6) and [gcc-4.7 [image: Install gcc-4.7]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gcc-4.7) packages installed in Quantal. I do a lot of software development but haven't had a need for any features that are specific to GCC 4.7. Therefore, in order to conserve space, I thought it would be a good idea to remove GCC 4.7. Unfortunately:

```
nathan@nathan-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove gcc-4.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  build-essential dkms g++ g++-4.7 gcc gcc-4.7 libstdc++6-4.7-dev nvidia-current-updates
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 8 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 250 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Here's where I become a little nervous. Some of the packages being removed (like `build-essential`) are just meta-packages and won't cause any problems. However, some of them I'm not so sure about. For example, `nvidia-current-updates` isn't a meta-package. In fact, it's a [66 MB package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/nvidia-current-updates). If it helps, I am using the Nvidia binary driver (Noveau doesn't work on my hardware).

Is it safe to continue? Will I lose anything important?

---

**Edit:** here is the output of `apt-cache rdepends gcc-4.7`:

```
gcc-4.7
Reverse Depends:
  gcc-4.7:i386
  llvm-gcc-4.7
  gccgo-4.7
  gcc-4.7-locales
  fixincludes
 |dragonegg-4.7
  gobjc-4.7
  gfortran-4.7
  gcj-4.7-jdk
  gcc-4.7-plugin-dev
  gcc-4.7-multilib
  gcc
  g++-4.7
  g++
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache rdepends gcc-4.7`? In my system (12.04.2) all nVidia drivers depends on gcc-4.6, so if you remove it(4.7) nVidia driver should go as well. Either way you should be able to remove `g++-4.7`. BTW: you can use `sudo apt-get autoremove gcc-4.7 --dry-run` to simulate what will happen.

Comment: @Salem: I've added the output.